How to lock certain letters in place, while shuffling the remaining letters in a series of letters?
I have the following letter sequence: "MGGGRYSGTK"
I wish to keep all the Gs in the same spot, but shuffle the remaining letters. The code I have so far is as follows. I need help on how to insert the G's back into their original place.
sequence <- "MGGGRYSGTK"

# Find the positions of Gs in the sequence
G_positions <- which(sequence == "G")

# Remove the Gs from the sequence
sequence_no_G <- gsub("G", "", sequence)

# Shuffle the remaining amino acids
shuffled_sequence_no_G <- paste(sample(strsplit(sequence_no_G, "")[[1]]), collapse = "")


I don't know R, so forgive me if this is already suggested as an answer, but a common approach is to shuffle sequence_no_G, and then substitute the letters in order into the original sequence.  If the sequence has a G, keep the G.  If it has any other letter, replace it with the next letter from the shuffled sequence.

Changing your idea on a minimal basis:
sequence = "MGGGRYSGTK"
x = strsplit(sequence, "")[[1L]]
x[i] = sample(x[i <- x != "G"]) 
paste(x, collapse = "") 
[1] "KGGGTMRGYS"


You can use utf8ToInt (and intToUtf8) + sample like below
s <- "MGGGRYSGTK"
f <- function(s, keep = "G") {
    sint <- utf8ToInt(s)
    idx <- sint != utf8ToInt(keep)
    intToUtf8(replace(sint, which(idx), sample(sint[idx])))
}

and you will see for exmaple
> f(s)
[1] "KGGGRSMGTY"


This seems like a nice opportunity to use the iterators package. Iterators maintain information about state, so make it easy to request the next element.

An iterator is a special type of object that generalizes the notion of a looping variable. When passed as an argument to a function that knows what to do with it, the iterator supplies a sequence of
values.

First split the string into a vector of letters, then iterate over the length of it, selecting (depending on which letter it is) either the desired letter or the next random letter offered by the iterator.
library(iterators)
swap_letters <- function(str, hold_letter = "G") {
    x <- unlist(strsplit(str, ""))
    swap <- iter(sample(x[x != hold_letter]))

    lapply(
        x,
        \(
            letter,
            s = swap,
            hl = hold_letter
        ) if (letter == hl) letter else nextElem(s)
    ) |>
        paste(collapse = "")
}

set.seed(42)
swap_letters("MGGGRYSGTK", "G") # "MGGGTKSGRY"
swap_letters("MGGGRYSGTK", "M") # "MGKGRGYTGS"


Using gregexpr() and regmatches():
sequence <- "MGGGRYSGTK"

g <- gregexpr("[^G]", sequence)
m <- regmatches(sequence, g)
regmatches(sequence, g) <- lapply(m, sample)
sequence
[1] "KGGGSRMGYT"


An option with grepRaw() and substring() could be:
shuffle_fun <- function(input, target_letter) {
 non_target_positions <- grepRaw(paste(setdiff(LETTERS, target_letter), collapse = "|"), input, all = TRUE)
 non_target_letters <- substring(input, non_target_positions, non_target_positions)
 sampled_non_target_letters <- sample(non_target_letters, length(non_target_letters))
 
 for(i in seq_along(non_target_positions)) {
  substring(input, non_target_positions[i], non_target_positions[i]) <- sampled_non_target_letters[i]
 }
 return(input)
}

shuffle_fun("MGGGRYSGTK", "G")
[1] "TGGGYSKGRM"

shuffle_fun("MGGGRYSGTK", "M")
[1] "MTGGYKSRGG"


I can never resist a timing test, so...
Benchmark
> foo = paste0(sample(c('M', 'G','R','Y','S','G','T','K'),1e3,replace=TRUE),collapse='')
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(tomcod(foo),friede(foo),samr(foo),tmfnk(foo), lotus(foo))
Unit: microseconds
        expr      min        lq       mean   median        uq       max neval
 tomcod(foo)   39.442   44.3620   49.82894   48.380   53.3000    78.515   100
 friede(foo)   98.031  114.1030  119.77289  118.203  123.2665   193.807   100
   samr(foo) 6497.598 6819.5710 7866.11609 7001.836 8198.3190 44381.229   100
  tmfnk(foo) 3461.958 3582.1700 3749.58981 3651.604 3716.8755  5675.999   100
  lotus(foo)  235.176  253.2365  276.51466  270.600  290.1365   458.011   100

EDIT TWO  friede submitted modded code.
microbenchmark(tomcod(foo),friede(foo),friede2(foo),lotus(foo),samr(foo),tmfnk(foo))
Unit: microseconds
         expr       min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval cld
  tomcod(foo)    65.941    73.6810    82.22718    80.0645    88.2710    122.788   100 a  
  friede(foo)   178.945   184.1595   192.02320   189.6940   196.6435    224.228   100 a  
 friede2(foo)   178.467   184.9555   193.34795   190.8725   200.9290    222.221   100 a  
   lotus(foo)   461.368   480.9220   535.46494   501.1280   523.5945   3717.288   100 a  
    samr(foo) 14625.145 14917.4965 19662.97214 15052.5340 15470.6325 161749.196   100  b 
   tmfnk(foo)  5746.362  5845.9695  7358.02076  5883.5455  5949.1420 150083.881   100   c

code used
tomcod <- function(s, keep = "G") {
    sint <- utf8ToInt(s)
    idx <- sint != utf8ToInt(keep)
    intToUtf8(replace(sint, which(idx), sample(sint[idx])))
}

friede <- function(s, keep = 'G'){
    x = strsplit(s, "")[[1L]]
x[i] = sample(x[i <- x != "G"]) 
paste(x, collapse = "")
}

friede2 = \(sequence) {
  x = strsplit(sequence, "")[[1L]]
  x[i] = sample(x[i <- x != "G"]) 
  paste(x, collapse = "") 
}

lotus <- function(s){
g <- gregexpr("[^G]", s)
m <- regmatches(s, g)
regmatches(s, g) <- lapply(m, sample)
return(s)
}
    
samr <- function(str, hold_letter = "G") {
    x <- unlist(strsplit(str, ""))
    swap <- iter(sample(x[x != hold_letter]))
    lapply(
        x,
        \(
            letter,
            s = swap,
            hl = hold_letter
        ) if (letter == hl) letter else nextElem(s)
    ) |>
        paste(collapse = "")
}

tmfnk  <- function(input, target_letter ='G') {
 non_target_positions <- grepRaw(paste(setdiff(LETTERS, target_letter), collapse = "|"), input, all = TRUE)
 non_target_letters <- substring(input, non_target_positions, non_target_positions)
 sampled_non_target_letters <- sample(non_target_letters, length(non_target_letters))
 for(i in seq_along(non_target_positions)) {
  substring(input, non_target_positions[i], non_target_positions[i]) <- sampled_non_target_letters[i]
 }
 return(input)
}


Nothing fancy, just a for loop that uses substring assignment. This is best kept in a function since substring assignment will modify the original value:
for_swap <- function(s, sav) {
  chr <- strsplit(s, "")[[1]]
  x <- sample(chr[chr != sav])
  idx <- which(chr != sav)
  for (i in seq_along(idx)) substr(s, idx[i], idx[i]) <- x[i]
  return(s)
}

It iterates over the indices that are not equal to the value you want to save (sav) and replaces them with values from a sample of other letters (x).
Output
set.seed(1)
for_swap(sequence, "G")
# [1] "MGGGSYKGRT"

